# Vector being perpendicular to a plane

Tags: vectors

Let us consider a vector $\vec P=x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k$. How do we test whether it is perpendicular or not to a certain plane?(We take $xy$ plane for simplicity).

My take on this was this. Let us consider a random vector $a\hat i+b\hat j$ on $xy$ plane. For $\vec P$ to be perpendicular to $xy$ plane,it must be perpendicular to $a\hat i+b\hat j$. Now from dot product $ax+by=0$ which in turn gives us a *restriction* on $a,b$ which these two must obey,but we wanted it to be perpendicular to $xy$ plane no matter what $a,b$ are without any restrictions. Also this approach got me nowhere. So,what will be correct method for testing it?

Comment: What information do we have on the plane? If we have its normal vector then it's rather simple

Comment: If $ax+by=0$ for every $a$ and $b$, the only solution is that $x=y=0$, which is good because the perpendicular vector is parallel to $\hat k$

Answer (score 1):

Your plane is a 2d linear subspace spanned by some vector $Span(v_1,v_2)$, (if it does not go through origin $0$ you could move it to be so. Since it's a linear subspace then it suffice to show that $v_1^T P=0,v_2^TP=0$ then any vector in this subspace is perpendicular to your vector.

To be concrete,

0. move your plane to pass through $(0,0,0)$
1. find two linear independent vectors from your plane
2. show that they are orthogonal to $P$.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we have a surface z = f(x,y).Any normal vector the the surface z  must be  $ \overrightarrow{n} = (kf_{x},kf_{y},-k) , k\epsilon \mathbb{Z}$ .

In order for $ \overrightarrow{c} $ to be perpendicular to $ \overrightarrow{n}$ $\overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{n}  = \overrightarrow{0} $

Comment: Use \in instead of \epsilon. Also a typo, $n$ and $c$ should be parallel. And not all planes are of that form, namely not the vertical ones.